# Fastlane- ld: library not found for -lPods-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension

Tags: react-native, onesignal, fastlane

I'm trying to integrate Fastlane sdk on React-Native project(iOS). so here is my current Fastfile:

```
lane :beta do
    tag = set_build_number
    build(method: "ad-hoc", scheme: "Beta")
    git_create(tag: ENV["LANE_NAME"]+"-"+tag)
end

private_lane :build do |options|
    cocoapods
    gym(
      scheme: project,
      workspace: "ABC.xcworkspace",
      configuration: options[:scheme],
      export_method: options[:method],
      include_bitcode: false,
    )
end
```

When I run `fastlane beta` on iOS directory, I got the following result:

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /Volumes/.../ios/Pods/YogaKit/YogaKit/Source/YGLayoutExtensions.swift
    Ld /Users/.../OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Binary/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension normal armv7
(2 failures)

...

❌  ld: library not found for -lPods-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension

❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any suggestion how to resolve this issue?